# Reverse of sum of (1,2,...,n)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

I'm developing a game. To reach level 6, a player needs 1+2+3+4+5+6=21 points.
Points need to reach level X = X.(X+1)/2

On the database, I store the points, not the level. I need to get a reverse function, on wich I give the total points a player have and the function returns on wich level that player is.

Comment: All you need to do is find the inverse function to $y = x(x+1)/2$. Swap $x$ and $y$, and then just solve for the new $y$.

Or if you're solely interested in the end result, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+f%28x%29+%3D+x%28x%2B1%29%2F2) can give you that; just need to account for floors/ceilings as you deem needed.

Comment: A [Gauss sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum) is not what you think it is.

Comment: Just make a second table  , keep the levels and points , anyhow this seems like a wrong way of implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a quadratic to solve $\dfrac{X(X+1)}{2}=p\iff X^2+X-2p=0$

Application of the formula gives $\ X=\frac 12(\sqrt{8p+1}-1)$

It gives you a decimal level, so you are probably more interested in calculating floor(X) to get an integer level.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. \o/

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the number by $2$, take the square root, and round down.

Comment: This is a seductive idea, but it's only working when $p$ is a triangular number, for intermediate values between two triangular numbers, it does not. This will cause the player to uplevel too soon. For instance we should switch to level $5$ at $15$ points but your formula allows it at only $13$ points.